# Transform parameters of an object into a nested array in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
let set = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: 'value3',
  key4: 'ignored',
  key5: 'also ignored'
}
```

I also have an array of keys, meant to keep track of which keys from the `set` object should used, as well as the nesting order:

```
let keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

How can I transform the `set` object into a nested object based on the hierarchy defined in `keys`? My desired output would look like this:

```
{
  key1: [{
    name: 'value1',
    key2: [{
      name: 'value2',
      key3: [{
        name: 'value3'
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Both `set` and `keys` could be of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the keys and return for each step the inner object.

```js
var set = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3', key4: 'ignored', key5: 'also ignored' },
    keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],
    result = {};

keys.reduce(function (o, k) {
    var temp = { name: set[k] };
    o[k] = [temp];
    return temp;
}, result);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Works perfectly!